# 'Unknown attribute' error in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to make my own simple authentication.
So I made User model and Users controller. And I have a form for sign up
Part of my Users controller.

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "You've successfully singed up."
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
```

And error:

> unknown attribute: password

In my Users table I have `username` and `password_digest` for each User. So there're not column like `password`.

I've just watched Rails Cast episode but it is about Rails 3 and author uses `attr_accessible` but I've read in Rails 4 we should use strong parameters.

How I can deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that you are using `has_secure_password` and you have not enabled it correctly. `has_secure_password` adds two virtual attributes to your model: `password` and `password_confirmation`. The error unknown attribute could mean that those two attributes are not being set correctly on your model.

You should under no circumstances pass the `password_digest` as a param since BCrypt and has_secure_password use this column to compute a hashed version of your password attribute. In other words it has no business being in the form.

Make sure you have:

1. Included the BCrypt gem in your gemfile
2. Correct included the `has_secure_password` module in your user model.

Your use of `strong_parameters` is correct. The problem is in your model, likely to do with has_secure_password, and not strong_paramters. So this line is correct:

```
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
```

Comment: Thank you :) I've had a typo in `has_secure_password` method.

Answer (score 1):

Strong parameters filter params to avoid mass assignments until they have been whitelisted.

The `permit` method identifies the list of allowed parameter and must correspond to your model's attributes.

So, in your case you should write

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:username, :password_digest)
end
```

Comment: But can I get from user some custom attributes? In rails 3 I think by `attr_accessible` you could get parameters which don't correspond to model. Or am I wrong?

Comment: This answer is wrong. First of all, he should not be passing `password_digest`. This is where Rails stores a computed hash from the password attribute. The password attribute, which is causing the error here, is a virtual attribute included  through has_secure_password. Under no circumstances whatsoever he should be passing this through a form. In fact, that attribute should never be touched at all. It's completely internal.

Comment: @Mohamad : I suggest to pass ````:password_digest```` because the OP said it's the name of his attribute in the User model.

Comment: @FredPerrin the error has nothing to do with Strong Parameters. It's an unknown attribute error. In other words he was setting an attribute that does not exist on the user.